# Finding rowwise minimum and column index in a tibble

Tags: r, purrr, tibble

I have the following tibble:

```
> df <- tibble(
     ID = LETTERS[1:4],
     a  = c(1,5,9,8),
     b  = c(5,9,8,2),
     c  = c(5,4,5,5)
)

> df
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  ID        a     b     c
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     5     5
2 B         5     9     4
3 C         9     8     5
4 D         8     2     5
>
```

What I want is to get the rowwise minimum of columns `a:c` and also the column index from this minimum.
The output tabel should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  ID        a     b     c   Min Col_Index
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A         1     5     5     1         1
2 B         5     9     4     4         3
3 C         9     8     5     5         3
4 D         8     2     5     2         2
```

I don't want to use `rowwise()`!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pmin` with `do.call` to get rowwise minimum and negate the values to use with `max.col` to get the column index of minimum.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(Min = do.call(pmin, select(., a:c)), 
         Col_Index = max.col(-select(., a:c)))

#  ID        a     b     c   Min Col_Index
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <int>
#1 A         1     5     5     1         1
#2 B         5     9     4     4         3
#3 C         9     8     5     5         3
#4 D         8     2     5     2         2
```

Using `purrr`'s `pmap_dbl` :

```
df %>%
  mutate(Min = pmap_dbl(select(., a:c), ~min(c(...))),
         Col_Index = pmap_dbl(select(., a:c), ~which.min(c(...))))
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `pmap_dbl`. See updated answer for that.

Comment: Perfect thank you Ronak Shah...this is what I have looked for.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(min = min(c_across(a:c)),
        min_index = which.min(c_across(a:c)))

  ID        a     b     c   min min_index
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <int>
1 A         1     5     5     1         1
2 B         5     9     4     4         3
3 C         9     8     5     5         3
4 D         8     2     5     2         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
setNames(cbind(df, t(apply(df[, vapply(df, is.numeric, logical(1))], 1, function(row) {
  cbind(min(row), which.min(row))}))), c(names(df), "min", "col_index"))
```